# How to write "AND" in LINQ

Tags: linq

```
var customer = _customerRepository.Single(c => c.Email == email)
```

I also want to say c=>c.psw == password.

For some restrictions, I have to use lambda expression. 
How to write such a query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `&&`:

```
var customer = _customerRepository.Single(c => c.Email == email &&
                                               c.Password == password);
```

Note that `Single` will throw an exception if the email or password is incorrect. This is most likely not an exceptional situation but simply an error in the user's input. Therefore it might be better to use `SingleOrDefault` and checking for `null` instead of using `Single` and catching the exception.

Comment: Also note that both SingleOrDefault and Single will throw if there is more than one match.